# How to initialize Hilt graph on background thread?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I writing an app and I would like to improve startup time. For that I want to initialize Hilt (Dagger) graph in background.

I have been reading **Dagger/Hilt/Hilt Jetpack compose** documentation. But I still can't find a method like `Hilt.create()` to initialize the graph.

Is it possible ? How to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure Dagger is the main source of slow app startup?

Comment: @skywall I never said that it's the main source. I need to improve startup time so I would like to optimize everything I can.